# SQL trigger to forbid deleting data newer than 2 weeks

Tags: postgresql, date, triggers, timestamp

I need help with creating a trigger which forbids user to delete data that is newer than 2 weeks.
My current code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_delete_data() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
 RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cant delete data which is newer than 2 weeks.';
 RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_delete_data BEFORE DELETE ON Results
 FOR EACH ROW WHEN (OLD.Date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) EXECUTE PROCEDURE
f_delete_data();
```

This code says there's a syntax error at or near 14 ..
Why is the `date_sub(..,interval 14 day)` not working?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.0.

Comment: Is your databse postgres?Add the tag.Also i suspect you need a BEGINNING adn END in there.

Comment: I think translating it was a bad idea, whether the language used in the code is english or not shouldn't affect our ability to determine a syntax error. I recommend that you post the code exactly as it is giving you the error. Any changes you make (like the `'` earlier) will produce inaccurate answers on our part.

Comment: @Mihai Added the tag & can't tell if I need BEGINNING and END because it won't compile anyway.

Comment: @BrandonBuck I just changed the exeption text and the function/trigger names - it should not affect the code in any way

Comment: Except that it already did affect it. I'm recommending you post the code as it is, in whatever language it's in. You should eliminate the possibility that renaming things has also introduced further issues. The only time it's really acceptable to "change" the code is when you're reducing the problem to it's simplest form to ask the question initially.

Comment: If you are serious about running 9.3.0, you should urgently upgrade to the latest point release (currently 9.3.5). Or possibly even to 9.4 (released 2 days ago). [Read more.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't the date_sub(..,intercval 14 day) not working?

`$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;` indicates you're using postgres however `DATE_SUB` is a MySQL specific function not available in postgres.

Try replacing `DATE_SUB` with this

`(OLD.Date < NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAYS')`

Comment: The problem may not be the `DATE_SUB` function, you quoted `14 days` in the interval call - he did not. Is that required?

Comment: @BrandonBuck although the `14 day` interval doesn't need to be quoted in mysql's `DATE_SUB`, it does need to be quoted when used with postgres's `INTERVAL`

Comment: MySQL? We're not talking about Postgres? I realize your answer was a valid solution. I was simply pointing out that he did not quote the `14 DAY` portion in his original query which is most likely the cause of his problem. He found a solution in your suggestion, which is great - I just wanted to bring up what could have potentially be the actual problem - more for future readers.

Comment: @BrandonBuck `date_sub` does not exist in postgres. Only changing the quotes would not have been enough

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious mistake (no `DATE_SUB` in Postgres), you also have your logic backwards. If you want to protect rows where the value in the `date` column is less than 2 weeks old: *"newer than 2 weeks"*, then you must revert the comparison operator.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_delete_data
BEFORE DELETE ON results
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))
WHEN (OLD.date < now() - interval '14 days')
WHEN (OLD.date > now() - interval '14 days')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_delete_data();
```

And <strike>`f_delete_data()`</strike> really should be name something like `f_protect_new_data()`.

Or, if your columns is an actual [**`date`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) like the ill-chosen column name suggests, further simplify:

```
WHEN (OLD.date >= CURRENT_DATE - 14)
```

[The manual on `CURRENT_DATE` & friends.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)
Use **`>=`** in this case, the 14th day back from today is still illegal according to your definition. The bound is logically a  bit different from `timestamp` handling.

Why "ill-chosen"? "date" is a [reserved word in standard SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and a basic type name in Postgres. If the column actually holds a `timestamp`, not a `date`, it's misleading on top of that.